# Looking for a software to shrink 12 hour long video to 5 minutes video

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I have 12hour long video ( 30fps ). I want to shrink it to just 5 mins.

12 hour * 30fps => total 1296000 frames
5 mins * 60ps => total 18000 frames
That means automatically pick every 72nd frame from the video. ( I don't know, my maths is really bad ;) )

Can you please suggest any free software to do this job?

Comment: Please specify your input and desired output video format (container + actual encoding). Your calculation looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this with the [framestep](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#framestep) filter.

- Free
- Cross Platform
- Supports most video types

Comment: Awesome. I think this is exactly what I needed. Also can I combine 300 clips of 3 minutes each into one using ffmpeg? Or any other software please suggest.

Comment: ffmpeg will also handle appending video clips, including replacing or mixing over the soundtrack, can cope with combining videos in different formats into one, change frame rate, aspect ratio, add captions, insert stills, etc.

Comment: It is almost 6 hours and ffmpeg is still converting.  12hours long video. Am I doing something wrong or does it really take that long. ( I have core i7, 8GB RAM, 2GB nvidia )

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to take that long - I would suggest testing with a much smaller video first - say 3-5 minutes - as an input, (but with the same format, frame rate, etc.), to get your settings correct.

Comment: You might find it worth using `ffmpeg -t 300 your_big_file.ext first_five.ext` where ext is the same for both, then you can experiment with first_five.